# Does micropython support pyotp?

Tags: python, micropython

I'm writing a program that runs on some lite device, like raspberry pi zero or ESP32. I hope it can act like a totp (Time-based one-time password) device, I'll set some tokens in it, and I hope it can show the dynamic password. Any help is significant to me, thanks!

this is my raw code, It works on my device, but I hope it can run in micropyhton:

```py
import json,pyotp,time,os

t = open("./data.json","r")
dat = json.loads(t.read())
t.close()

while True:
    os.system('cls')
    os.system('clear')

    for s in dat.keys():
        print(s,pyotp.TOTP(dat[s]).now())
    
    time.sleep(10)
```

`data.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "<name>":"<token>",
    "<name2>":"<token2>",
    "<name3>":"<token3>",
    ....
}
```

I googled to find this , but I'cant find some useful solution.

Comment: What happens if you try to run it in micropython?

Comment: Modules written for regular python (like `pyotp`) **will not** work with MicroPython. The languages are *similar*, but they are not the same. It's possible you could implement the necessary functionality yourself, but I don't know if all of the necessary cryptographic primitives will be available in MicroPython.

Comment: There are multiple project for that, one of them, looks quite complete and Open Source https://eddmann.com/posts/building-a-2fa-totp-generator-using-a-raspberry-pi-pico-and-micropython/